# Why would $(window).width() be larger than CSS max-width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my CSS I have code like this:

```
html {
background:blue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
html {
background:red;
}
```

So when the browser window is less than 980px, background turns red, the rest of the time, it is blue.

I resized my window to 970px (according to CSS) and the background is red.  But when I use jquery to do a `alert($(window).width())`, which gave me a pop up saying 1000px

Why would $(window).width() reporting a larger value than what CSS expects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerWidth and outerWidth oddness on desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468878/innerwidth-and-outerwidth-oddness-on-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

In chrome, i pressed CTRL MINUS a few times so the window scaled in a way to have smaller text.  Once this is done, jquery wil report a different window width from what css report

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a difference between the visible page and the window size. In vanilla JS, so far as I understand:

```
window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight
```

(the page's visible width/height)

```
window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight
```

(the browser outer width/height)

It strikes me that this is probably why - the value being returned is the outer width of the browser window. [Source](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough of background to tell you what exactly happens in your browser.

I wrote the following page to test everything out:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    html { background:blue; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
        html { background:red; }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>test</body>
</html>
```

And after testing it with the inspector, `$(window).width()` inside of the Chromium inspector shows exactly what it should be.

While screen is red, following style is set in inspector:

```
margin-left: 8px;
margin-right: 8px;
width: 964px;
```

...and jquery in console shows:

```
> $(window).width()
980
```

Total width is the width + all the margins. So, it is: 964 + 8 + 8 = 980.

In my opinion, this inconsistency is caused by **margins** and possibly borders set for tags you are measuring and any parent tags. I don't see any other reasons of this behaviour.

I hope this helps.