# innerWidth and outerWidth oddness on desktop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Open the console in chrome (whilst on SO) and copy in `innerWidth + "|"+outerWidth + "|" + screen.width`, for me this will return `2133|1920|1920`, apparantly the `innerWidth` is greater than the `outerWidth`... As if this isn't strange enough I next tried running this code in firefox and it returns `1920|1936|1920`. Apparantly my `outerWidth` is greater than my screen size. (All screens were normally maximized). Strangely enough running the same code on a 'normal' page (not stackoverflow) will return `1920|1920|1920` in chrome, firefox however still insists my `outerWidth` is greater than my screen.

Have looked around on google, found a couple of articles regarding the functionality on mobile devices, but nothing seems to explain any of the above observation.

Comment: I'm basically seeing the same thing. Not sure what you mean by *normal page*, but the websites I tried give me the same results in the respective browsers. I tried SO, google.com, and amazon.com. (1920, 1936, 1920) in Firefox and (1920, 1920, 1920) in Chrome for all 3 sites.

Comment: `outerWidth` can in fact be bigger than the screen size if there is window chrome that's just off the edge of the screen..

Comment: I'm having the same trouble with Chrome: `1422|1280|1280`. It's driving me a little nuts because it's affecting my breakpoints (which use the `innerWidth`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One reason `innerWidth` could be larger than `outerWidth` is if your browser is zoomed. I got the following results with the browser in fullscreen mode:

```
zoom  inner  outer
75%   1706   1280
90%   1422   1280
100%  1280   1280
110%  1164   1280
```

The only way I could get `outerWidth` to be larger than `screen.width` is by changing the window width by dragging.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference between getting of innerWidth and outerWidth.
Look at official definitions:

> **Window.innerWidth:** is Width (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the vertical scrollbar.
>
> **Window.outerWidth:** The outerWidth attribute must return the width of the client window.

As you can see innerWidth has bound to **viewport** width, while outerWidth has bound to **browser window** width.

Therefore **outerWidth** can be less than **innerWidth** when your page is just zoomed in, or page view is scaled up.
I think you need to state folloving tag in your page:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It will make you page to behave as expected (fit to width limits of screen) in small viewports.

And as a possible cause of large innerWidth is the scripts or styles that can change window dimensions.

Comment: still not working. I have to move ball from left to right corner but due to innerWidth being greater than my screensize. ball move past my screensize & i have to scroll what can I do

Answer (score 0):

If we take the MDN definition of [window.outerWidth:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth)

> Window.outerWidth read-only property returns the width of the outside
>   of the browser window. It represents the width of the whole browser
>   window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window
>   resizing borders/handles.

And for [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth):

> The read-only Window property innerWidth returns the interior width of
>   the window in pixels. This includes the width of the vertical scroll
>   bar if one is present.

[image]

### Concluding:

1. The outerHeight and outerWidth take into account the browser window size and not the html visible size. Because of that, the values can change from browser to browser and device to device. Moreover, the values can be larger than the device screen itself.
2. The innerWidth value includes the scroll if present. This means the width value will not be only referring to the visible part but also the amount of scroll left which could be greater than window.outerWidth.